# Cannot open or create a new text file in LibreOffice 7.3 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice

A few days ago I upgraded from Ubuntu 21.04 to Ubuntu 22.04, and since then I cannot open or create a new text file / doc file in LibreOffice 7.3. It always shows a message box that says:

> The file 'New.docx' is corrupt and therefore cannot be opened. LibreOffice can try to repair the file.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: What happens if you answers YES to let OO repair the  file. as suggested in the error text  ?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 had one intended upgrade path, which was to Ubuntu 21.10  (*when could then be upgraded to 22.04*), and a re-install is required to upgrade to Ubuntu Core 22 as it's a different system (*22.04 & 22 are different Ubuntu products*);  22 is for *headless* use only with only 22.04 available for server or desktop use. You mention an *unsupported* upgrade path, so problems could have been expected; please stick to QA tested & *supported* upgrade paths for best results.

Comment: I seem to remember this happened to someone who had set their default character set to UTF16 instead of UTF8.

Comment: @guiverc The version of LibreOffice in this question (7.3) is specific to Ubuntu 22.04, so I tagged this question with 22.04 to make it clearer. This indicates a skipped upgrade and problems could be expected with a skipped upgrade as you noted, although maybe it is not a critical problem in this case since the corrupt document can be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the LibreOffice snap package in the Software app. I tried it and it works OK. There are no bugs at all. You can either keep the existing LibreOffice apt package installed or else uninstall it.

Alternatively open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install libreoffice
```

`

Comment: if i click for repairing it fails. i tried with different docx file but i could not open any file or can not write a new word file

Comment: Try installing the LibreOffice snap package in the Software app. I tried it and it works good.